# plot array from matrix matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in MATLAB like this:

```
day1 =

       1         964
       1         893
       2          15
       2          14
       3         882
       2          15
       2          15
       1         942
       2          16
       3          17
       4        1993
```

In the first column I have the label of an activity and in the column 2 the length of the activity (in seconds);
My aim is to plot these activities during the time sequentially (X axis will be the time and Y axis will be the activity).
How can I do this in Matlab?

Comment: What would your preferred plot look like?

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, it should basically look like

```
day1 = [  1         964;
          1         893;
          2          15;
          2          14;
          3         882;
          2          15;
          2          15;
          1         942;
          2          16;
          3          17;
          4        1993];

x = cumsum(day1(:,2));
y = day1(:,1);

plot(x,y);
```

[image: output]